# comparing iterators in C++

Tags: c++, iterator

I am confused on comparing iterators in C++. With the following code:

```
std::iterator< std::forward_iterator_tag, CP_FileSystemSpec> Iter1;
std::iterator< std::forward_iterator_tag, CP_FileSystemSpec> Iter2;

while( ++Iter1 != Iter2 )
{

}
```

The error is:

```
error: no match for 'operator++' in '++Iter1'
```

I seem to recall that you could not do what the code above is doing. But I dont quite know how to do the comparison.

Answer (score 6):

`std::iterator` is not an iterator in itself, but a base class other iterators could inherit from to get a few standard typedefs.

```
template<class Category, class T, class Distance = ptrdiff_t, class Pointer = T*, class Reference = T&> 
struct iterator 
{ 
    typedef T value_type; 
    typedef Distance difference_type; 
    typedef Pointer pointer; 
    typedef Reference reference; 
    typedef Category iterator_category; 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This error has nothing to do with the comparison- it's telling you that that specific iterator does not support incrementing.

Comment: so how does one overcome something like this. I assume that I could add incrementing for this iterator in a header for where this is defined?

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to derive from `std::iterator` -- instantiating it directly makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

To make that sample work, use an iterator that is backed by an sequence, for instance a `vector`:

```
std::vector<int> foo(10); // 10 times 0

std::vector<int>::iterator it1 = foo.begin();
std::vector<int>::iterator it2 = foo.end();

while(++it1 != it2) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Note that this is not the canonical way to iterate over a collection. It is also tricky, because it skips the first element of the sequence. Use this:

```
for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = foo.begin(); it != foo.end(); it++) {
    // do stuff
}
```